# MySQL Relations

Tags: mysql, database

I have multiple tables containing different data. Some fields exist in other tables and are related to eachother. How could I make it that if I update field A in table A the related field in table C automatically updates too?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

You need to create or update the FK to Cascade the change

```
FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES parent(id)
                      ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

For more see the documentation on [FOREIGN KEY Constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html)

Comment: What about multiple fields, I got one INT and one VARCHAR, @ varchar it only lets me choose the internal INT

Comment: not sure if I understood your comment. You've got a varchar that references a int?

Comment: I also have a varchar field in the same tables I want to relate, but it won't let me

Comment: I can't see your image (its blocked where I am), but I'm guessing you're not meeting the requirements for creating the FK. e.g. The referenced value isn't indexed.

Comment: SQL query:

ALTER TABLE `ge` ADD FOREIGN KEY ( `item_name` ) REFERENCES `herpius`.`items` (
`item_name`
) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE ;

MySQL said: Documentation
#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`herpius`.<result 2 when explaining filename '#sql-1350_219'>, CONSTRAINT `#sql-1350_219_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`item_name`) REFERENCES `items` (`item_name`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)